# How to use two pointers to iterate a linked list in Rust?

Tags: rust

I just started to learn Rust lang and tried to do some practices on Leetcode. I'm working the problem [Middle of the Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/).

The solution is just to use the slow and fast pointer. This is my code in Rust:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode {
            next: None,
            val
        }
    }
}

struct Solution;
impl Solution {
    pub fn middle_node(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let slow = &head;
        let fast = &head;
        while fast.is_some() && fast.unwrap().next.is_some() {
            slow = &(slow.unwrap().next);
            fast = &(fast.unwrap().next.unwrap().next);
        }
        *slow
    }
}
```

However, I got a lot of complier errors like:

```
  --> src/main.rs:22:33
   |
22 |         while fast.is_some() && fast.unwrap().next.is_some() {
   |                                 ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I understand that I violated the borrower check rules that I cannot take out something from an immutable ref, but how should I achieve this two-pointer implementation?

Any suggestions will help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're exactly right that your problem is you're trying to move something out of a borrowed object. First, let's take a look at your signature.

```
pub fn middle_node(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
```

This function is taking ownership of `head` and returning ownership of (some sublist of) the list. This is undoubtedly not what you want, because it would invalidate any other references to the list. In this case, we want to borrow the argument and return another reference.

```
pub fn middle_node(head: &Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> &Option<Box<ListNode>> {
```

No ownership changes hands. And no ownership needs to change hands; the caller will own the list at the start and it will own the list at the end.

Now, you assign to `fast` and `slow`, so they need to be mutable. You can't reassign to an ordinary `let`.

```
let mut slow = head;
let mut fast = head;
```

(I also removed the `&head`, as `head` is now already a reference, so we don't need to take a ref anymore)

Now, finally, as you said, you are trying to *move* the value out of the option every time, which is both unnecessary and confusing to the borrow checker. Fortunately, `Option` provides a convenient way to take a reference to the inside. `as_ref` takes an `Option<T>` and turns it into a `Option<&T>`, so we can borrow the inside. We need to `as_ref` before each time that we `unwrap`. For example,

```
while fast.is_some() && fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
```

(Notice the `as_ref`) And the same thing in all of the other places you `unwrap` an optional value. Finally, the returned `*slow` simply becomes `slow`, since again `slow` is already a reference and we're returning a reference now.

Runnable code:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode {
            next: None,
            val
        }
    }
}

struct Solution;
impl Solution {
    pub fn middle_node(head: &Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> &Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let mut slow = head;
        let mut fast = head;
        while fast.is_some() && fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
            slow = &(slow.as_ref().unwrap().next);
            fast = &(fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.as_ref().unwrap().next);
        }
        slow
    }
}

fn arr_to_list(arr: &[i32]) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut head = None;
    for n in arr {
        let mut new_node = ListNode::new(*n);
        new_node.next = head;
        head = Some(Box::new(new_node));
    }
    head
}

fn main() {
    let node = arr_to_list(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
    let mid = Solution::middle_node(&node);
    println!("Middle node is {}", mid.as_ref().unwrap().val)
}
```

Comment: Hi Silvio, really appreciate for your answer. I think the method signature **middle_node(head: &Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> &Option<Box<ListNode>>** is defined by Leetcode, I probably should report this bug to them.

Comment: Also, seems like Option<T>.as_ref().unwrap() is a common use scenario, I would wonder why we don't have a method combine them together in the core library. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, `unwrap` tends to be discouraged except in small programs like this. `Option` has a lot of other ways of peering into it that don't involve panicking (`unwrap_or`, `ok_or`, etc), all of which need the same `as_ref` call to ensure borrowing.

Comment: I agree with you that this should be reported to Leetcode if they really did defining an owning type signature for that function. It's possible that they simply did so for all the challenges without really thinking about it (easy to do if you're writing a challenge that's supposed to support several languages), and it should really be brought to their attention.

Answer (score 1):

Based on great answer by Silvio Mayolo: in case we need to deal with borrowed object inside the method (Leetcode is still using that signature), we can use ref to node for finding right one and than consider cloning in the end:

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn middle_node(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let mut slow = &head;
        let mut fast = &head;

        while fast.is_some() && fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
            slow = &slow.as_ref().unwrap().next;
            fast = &fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.as_ref().unwrap().next;
        }

        slow.clone()
    }
}
```