# What is the difference between `&mut retval` and `retval as *const T as *mut T`?

Tags: rust

I am having a hard time trying to understand why the following code has 2 different behaviors:

```
pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> &T {
    let arr = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts(self.elements, self.count) };
    &arr[idx]
}
```

when I call:

```
unsafe { ptr::drop_in_place(self.get(i) as *const T as *mut T) };
```

it works and the value is dropped in place, however changing the cast to `&mut` does not:

```
unsafe { ptr::drop_in_place(&mut self.get(i)) };
```

I expected the compiler to yield an error since `T` does not support clone/copy, but it's not the case. What is the explanation?

Minimal Example:

```
use core::*;

pub struct Vec<T> {
    elements: *mut T,
    count: usize,
    capacity: usize,
}

pub fn alloc_array<T>(count: usize) -> *mut T {
    let size = mem::size_of::<T>() * count;
    let addr = unsafe { libc::memalign(mem::size_of::<usize>(), size) as *mut T };
    unsafe { libc::memset(addr as *mut libc::c_void, 0, size) };
    addr
}

pub fn free_array<T>(arr: *mut T) {
    unsafe { libc::free(arr as *mut libc::c_void) };
}

impl<T> Vec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            elements: ptr::null_mut(),
            count: 0,
            capacity: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.count
    }

    pub fn pushBack(&mut self, t: T) {
        if self.count >= self.capacity {
            let newSize = if self.capacity == 0 {
                16
            } else {
                self.capacity * 2
            };
            let old = self.elements;
            self.elements = alloc_array(newSize);
            self.capacity = newSize;

            let oldArr = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(old, self.count) };
            let newArr = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.elements, self.count + 1) };

            for i in 0..self.count {
                let v = unsafe { ptr::read(&oldArr[i] as *const _) };
                newArr[i] = v;
            }
        }
        let arr = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.elements, self.count + 1) };

        arr[self.count] = t;
        self.count += 1
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.count == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            self.count -= 1;
            Some(unsafe { ptr::read(self.get(self.count) as *const _) })
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> &T {
        let arr = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts(self.elements, self.count) };
        &arr[idx]
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for Vec<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropped");
        for i in 0..self.count {
            //unsafe { ptr::drop_in_place(self.get(i) as *const T as *mut T) };   // Works
            unsafe { ptr::drop_in_place(&mut self.get(i)) }; // Doesn't Works
        }
        if self.capacity != 0 {
            free_array(self.elements);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::<Vec<i32>>::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let mut vj = Vec::<i32>::new();
        for j in 0..10 {
            vj.pushBack(j);
        }
        v.pushBack(vj);
    }
}
```

Valgrind:

```
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
Dropped
==6887== 
==6887== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6887==     in use at exit: 640 bytes in 10 blocks
==6887==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 20 frees, 4,433 bytes allocated
==6887== 
==6887== Searching for pointers to 10 not-freed blocks
==6887== Checked 107,320 bytes
==6887== 
==6887== 640 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==6887==    at 0x4C320A6: memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6887==    by 0x10CB3F: minimal_test::alloc_array (main.rs:11)
==6887==    by 0x10CDDC: minimal_test::Vec<T>::pushBack (main.rs:35)
==6887==    by 0x10E1BB: minimal_test::main (main.rs:85)
==6887==    by 0x10C2DF: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}} (rt.rs:67)
==6887==    by 0x1165B2: {{closure}} (rt.rs:52)
==6887==    by 0x1165B2: std::panicking::try::do_call (panicking.rs:305)
==6887==    by 0x117D16: __rust_maybe_catch_panic (lib.rs:86)
==6887==    by 0x116F3F: try<i32,closure-0> (panicking.rs:281)
==6887==    by 0x116F3F: catch_unwind<closure-0,i32> (panic.rs:394)
==6887==    by 0x116F3F: std::rt::lang_start_internal (rt.rs:51)
==6887==    by 0x10C2B8: std::rt::lang_start (rt.rs:67)
==6887==    by 0x10E259: main (in minimal-test/target/debug/minimal-test)
==6887== 
==6887== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6887==    definitely lost: 640 bytes in 10 blocks
==6887==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6887==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6887==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6887==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6887== 
==6887== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==6887== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: How are you checking whether the `ptr::drop_in_place` call "works"? Some more code (and a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) would be nice.

Comment: used valgrind and added a minimal example.

Comment: `Doesn't Works` is vague. Does it result in compilation error? In runtime error? What is the error description. `I expected the compiler to yield` So does the code compile, but you expected it not to, and this is the reason is "doesn't work"? `640 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost` - you do not free memory allocated in `pushBack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay close attention to types.

```
pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> &T {
```

`self.get(i)` has type `&T`. So `&mut self.get(i)` has type `&mut &T`. Calling `drop_in_place` will coerce `&mut &T` to `*mut &T` and drop a `&T`, which (because shared references do not implement `Drop`) does nothing.

`self.get(i) as *const _ as *mut _` casts `&T` to `*const T` and then to `*mut T`. **Calling `drop_in_place` will invoke undefined behavior when it calls `<T as Drop>::drop`, which accepts a `&mut T`.** This is bad.

You cannot mutate a value (including dropping it) through a shared reference. Casting through raw pointers doesn't make it possible. See [Is there a way to make an immutable reference mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237610/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-immutable-reference-mutable)

The [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec.html) contains a section on implementing `Vec<T>` from scratch; I suggest reading it.

Comment: can you please elaborate on: "Calling drop_in_place will invoke undefined behavior when the drop method is called, which turns the *mut T into a &mut T." ?
I cannot see why this is the case by reading `drop_in_place` doc.

Comment: @kin It says "Executes the destructor of the pointed-to value." The destructor is [`Drop::drop(&mut self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html#tymethod.drop).

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful. I had to make a simpler example with 'i32' to validate the reasoning and indeed it's been coerced as `&mut &T` forcing `drop_in_place` to drop a double pointer (doing nothing). Curse of generics :)